# button state inconsistency after alert() execution causes involuntary double submit

Tags: javascript, button, state, alert, dashcode

A dashcode's "Lozenge" button element remain "pressed" or clicked after an alert gets displayed inside the button's onclick handler. Then, if I click anywhere in the same page, the onclick event gets fired again.

When I get the second (undesired) data submission, I also get the following js error: Parts/core/views/Page.js line 378: TypeError: Result of expression 'event.targetTouches[0]' [undefined] is not an object.

I tried to hide the button before the alert and show it after, with no change of behavior at all.

Any thoughts ? Suggestion ? Solutions ?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: is this in a desktop widget or a web app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my web app. What it solved for me was to add following line to the onclick handler:

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_BUTTON').object._setPressed(false);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No Luck. I tried to add the _setpressed(false) method call before and after the alert() call, but nothing changes.